# NameError in Python Nested for loops of List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops

**Scenerio:**

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(i):
        j
```

AFAIK, in list comprehension the right most `for` is the outer one so, I thought the following code will work:

```
[ j for j in range(i) for i in range(6)]
```

But to my surprise, it throws a `NameError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

I wonder why it didn't work. Is it because python evaluates expression from *Left to Right*? 
Cause, I have resolved the issue by using parenthesis:

```
[ (j for j in range(i)) for i in range(6)]
```

which outputs a bunch of generator expressions:

```
[<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7f3b42200d00>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7f3b42200d58>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7f3b42200db0>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7f3b42200e08>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7f3b42200e60>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7f3b42200eb8>]
```

To explore what is inside these generator expressions we can simply cast them into lists i.e.

```
[ list(j for j in range(i )) for i in range(6)]
```

and the output is as expected:

```
[[], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I just want to know what is really happening here.

Comment: `[ j for i in range(6) for j in range(i)]` Try this

Comment: I cannot tell you exactly why the command is interpreted the way it is, but to get the expected behavior out of the box, use ``[ j for j in (range(i) for i in range(6))]``

Comment: "the right most for is the outer one". No, the order is the same as "traditional" for loops. I think you got confused by looking at a nested list comprehension, eg `[[j for j in range(i)] for i in range(6)]`.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, I was confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, it's evaluated from left to right. To add the others' answers, I looked up [the official explanation in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.0.html?highlight=comprehension%20evaluate#list-comprehensions).

> List comprehensions have the form:

```
 [ expression for expr in sequence1
              for expr2 in sequence2 ...
              for exprN in sequenceN
              if condition ]
```

> The `for…in` clauses contain the sequences to be iterated over. The
>   sequences do not have to be the same length, because they are not
>   iterated over in parallel, but from *left to right*; this is explained
>   more clearly in the following paragraphs. The elements of the
>   generated list will be the successive values of expression. The final
>   if clause is optional; if present, expression is only evaluated and
>   added to the result if condition is true.
>
> To make the semantics very clear, a list comprehension is equivalent
>   to the following Python code:

```
for expr1 in sequence1:
    for expr2 in sequence2:
    ...
        for exprN in sequenceN:
             if (condition):
                  # Append the value of
                  # the expression to the
                  # resulting list.
```

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
j for j in range(i) for i in range(6)
```

just like :

```
for j in range(i):
    for i in range(6):
        j
```

outer loop uses `i` before it is defined, so `NameError` occurred, i.e. your belief "the right most for is the outer one" is wrong.

You can use this code

```
[j for i in range(6) for j in range(i)]
```

and why below code work

```
[ (j for j in range(i)) for i in range(6)]
# parentheses make it work like this
for i in range(6):
     for j in range(i):
          j
```

Comment: Thank you, so if we don't use parenthesis the left most for will be considered as the outer loop! I didn't know that.