# understanding the different functions in a line of code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm on hackerrank working on this question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/botcleanlarge

many submissions had extremely long lines of code.
then there was this:

```
def next_move(posr, posc, board):
    i, j = min(((i, j) for i, row in enumerate(board) if 'd' in row for j, c in enumerate(row) if c == 'd'), key=lambda x: abs(posr - x[0]) + abs(posc - x[1]))
    print("LEFT" if j < posc else "RIGHT" if j > posc else "UP" if i < posr else "DOWN" if i > posr else "CLEAN")
```

I roughly understand that it is trying to find the next nearest cell. But it's all mashed up and I'm having a really hard time trying to break it down and understand it.

if it is not too must a bother, can someone kindly break down the first line of the function for me? say rewrite it out in multiple lines which would be more readable?

I tried breaking it up at the commas:

```
def next_move(posr, posc, board):
     i, j = min((
    (i, j) for i, row in enumerate(board) 
    if 'd' in row for j, 
    c in enumerate(row) if c == 'd'), 
    key=lambda x: abs(posr - x[0]) + abs(posc - x[1]))
```

but i still really have no idea what it is doing. 
Generally, I do understand "if", "for", "enumerate", and roughly what "key=lambda" means (in this case, decide the minimum by comparing value of x, am i right?)

please help me out :/

Comment: key would be some variable on which lambda function is applied. It means for every x do absolute of `posr -x[0]` and add it with absolute of `posc -x[1]`

Comment: that code mashes list comprehension inside a `min(listcomp, key=lambda function)` in a single line.  take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565893/nameerror-in-python-nested-for-loops-of-list-comprehension/52566100#52566100

Answer (score 2):

Breaking down mechanically by comma is not useful if you don't understand the involved syntactic constructs. I go outside-in, matching parentheses; `min` is a function, taking up one pair. It has two arguments, the first one is a big parenthetical expression - a comprehension, as it turns out - while the second one is a named argument. In the comprehension, we have the generating expression, and two `for...if` clauses, both of which iterate over pairs generated by `enumerate`.

```
i, j = min(
    (
        (i, j)
        for i, row in enumerate(board) if 'd' in row
        for j, c in enumerate(row) if c == 'd'
    ),
    key=lambda x: abs(posr - x[0]) + abs(posc - x[1])
)
```

So assuming `board` is a list of strings, it looks for rows containing `d` and characters within those rows that are `d`, generates pairs of the respective indices (coordinates), then finds the pair with lowest Manhattan distance to `(posr, posc)`.

Comment: what are the commas for? those after "for i" and "for j"? sorry i'm still trying to grasp the logic of the clauses.

Comment: does it mean for row in enumerate(board), if there's a 'd', that will be i's value?

Comment: `enumerate` generates pairs of `(index, element)`. For example, `enumerate(["a", "b"])` will generate the pair `(0, "a")` and then the pair `(1, "b")`. `for i, row in enumerate(board)` will assign this pair to the pair of variables `i, row`: `i` becomes the index, `row` becomes the element of the `board` list.